# Как сделать обозначения длины бана в discord.py?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

У меня получилось сделать длительность бана:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, reason):
  await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} **забанен** \n Продолжительность бана: *{time}h* \n Причина бана: *{reason}*')
  await member.send(f'Тебя забанили на сервере {ctx.guild.name} по причине {reason}')
  await member.ban(reason=reason)
  await asyncio.sleep(time * 3600)
  await member.unban()
  await ctx.send(f'*У {member.mention} закончился бан*')
  link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age=300)
  await member.send(f'У тебя закончился бан на сервере "{ctx.guild.name}"! {link}')
```

Но я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог вводить не только время в часах, но и в других единицах. Например: `!ban @тест 1h тест` или `!ban @тест 10d тест` `2m` и т.д...

Как можно это реализовать?
Если что пишу на *replit*

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы реализовать такую функцию, придется убрать у аргумента `time` привязку к типу `int`

`time: int` -> `time`

Теперь, когда имеем строку формата `[Время][тип]`, мы можем разбить ее по такому принципу:

```
time_type = time[-1] # последний символ, содержащий s, m, h, d ...

try:
    time = int(time[:-1]) # в переменной time теперь записано все, кроме последнего символа, тип int
except:
    await ctx.send('Введите число')
```

Ну и затем, если `time_type` это `h`, то умножаем `time` на `3600` и т.д.